# What happen with coroutines when main thread exits?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In Java when main thread exits, all user threads (non-deamon threads) will keep running until they finish their job.

I have a simple program which print a counter from 1 to 5 to console.

**Java version:**

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Main start")

    countWithThread()

    println("Main end")
}

fun countWithThread() {
    Thread(Runnable {
        for (i in 1..5) {
            println("${Thread.currentThread().name} count $i")
            Thread.sleep(10)
        }
    }).start()
}
```

Output:

```
Main start
Main end
Thread-0 count 1
Thread-0 count 2
Thread-0 count 3
Thread-0 count 4
Thread-0 count 5

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Kotlin version:**

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Main start")

    countWithCoroutine()

    println("Main end")
}

fun countWithCoroutine() {
    launch(CommonPool) {
        for (i in 1..5) {
            println("${Thread.currentThread().name} count $i")
            delay(10)
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Main start
Main end

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you can see, when main thread exits, the code in the coroutine does not run anymore. It seems Kotlin terminate all coroutines under the hood.

Can anyone tell me what exactly happen with coroutines when main thread exits?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Coroutines on their own aren't "running" in a way that the JVM would know about. They're nothing but objects on the heap.

However, the *coroutine context* does have a say in when it will allow the JVM to terminate. Create your own:

```
val threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)
val dispatcher = threadPool.asCoroutineDispatcher()
```

Now if you use it instead of `CommonPool`:

```
launch(dispatcher) { ... }
```

you'll find the JVM doesn't die at all, even when all the tasks are done. It will exit only when you explicitly say

```
threadPool.shutdown()
```

Note, however, that `threadPool.shutdown()` doesn't behave towards coroutines the same as towards the "classic" tasks you submit to it. The executor will ensure all the submitted tasks are done before shutting down, but it has no account of the suspended coroutines.

Comment: So coroutines will be killed or keep running are based on `coroutine context` implementation. If all threads in coroutine context are deamon-threads (e.g.,  `CommonPool`) then it will be killed, if all threads in coroutine context are user-threads then it will keep running until finishing their job. Each time I try to use a coroutine context I must see the underlying implementation of it. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: As long as there is a _single_ non-daemon thread, the JVM keeps running. A coroutine isn't always bound to a single context, using `withContext` you can temporarily send it to another one. Furthermore, issuing `pool.shutdown()` won't ensure all the coroutines are done before shutting down, unlike the Java tasks you submit to the pool. That's because a suspended coroutine isn't accounted for anywhere inside the threadpool, it's in Kotlin's structures.

Comment: `"pool.shutdown() won't ensure all the coroutines are done before shutting down"`. Does it mean the coroutines will be killed but it might be in `inconsistent state`?

Comment: Try to avoid thinking in terms of "killing" a coroutine. A suspended coroutine is nothing but an object with a `resume()` method, which you may or may not call. You don't have to take any forceful action to "kill" it; you must make some explicit effort to get it going again. In most cases it's some framework code that does it, but the basic principle stands.

Answer (score 5):

Coroutines are terminated when the main thread finishes execution and the process/JVM instance dies, they are like daemon threads. See [this section](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md#coroutines-are-like-daemon-threads) in the official coroutine guide for reference.

Comment: Does it mean all threads in `CommonPool` which coroutines running on are deamon-threads by default.

Comment: Yes, `CommonPool` is a [`ForkJoinPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) when you're running on the JVM, which uses daemon threads.