# How keep run a coroutines forever?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a `Poller` class that runs polling operation to retrive data from an API (All operations are async thanks to coroutines). Following an example class:

```kotlin
class Poller() {
    private var isRunning = false
    private var job: Job? = null

    init {
        isRunning = true
        job = GlobalScope.launch {
            while (isRunning) {
                launch { updater() }

                delay(10_000)
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

My main:

```kotlin
fun main() = runBlocking {
    val poller = Poller()

    // do other stuff or nothings
}
```

The main thread execute the line: `val poller = Poller()`, exit and stops the app.

How can I keep running in the background the `Poller` (so I can runs other stuff or do nothing)?

**EDIT:**
I try to replace the `GlobalScope.launch { ... }` with:

```kotlin
val threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)
val dispatcher = threadPool.asCoroutineDispatcher()

job = CoroutineScope(dispatcher).launch {
   while (isRunning) {
        launch { clanUpdater() }
        delay(10_000)
   }
}
```

But the app stops anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happen with coroutines when main thread exits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52196187/what-happen-with-coroutines-when-main-thread-exits)

Comment: Also, 1) Don't use `GlobalScope`, 2) don't start coroutines in constructors like that.

Comment: I try white: `CoroutineScope(dispatcher).launch { ... }` but the app stops anyway.

Comment: You're not doing anything in `main()` to wait for the coroutine. Using `CoroutineScope(dispatcher).launch` is no different than using `GlobalScope.launch(dispatcher)`. All that is internal to your Poller class. `main()` doesn't know or care about it. You need to expose `job.join()` through a public function that can be called by `main()`.

Comment: @Jorn, what's the reason for you point 2? It's not relying on the internals of the coroutine to complete construction of the class. Regarding point 1, GlobalScope is appropriate for coroutines that are intended to last for the lifetime of the application.

Comment: Thanks @Tenfour04, with the `job.join()` the `main()` stops correctly.

Comment: Your `updater()` function looks suspicious. Why does it need to be run asynchronously? Do you have multiple updating functions running in parallel?

Comment: You need to use `supervisorScope { }` around the while loop, or any failure from one of the `updater()` calls will take down your whole app.

Comment: Oh ok, I'm trying to learn Kotlin so I'm a bit noob. Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: To clarify, by take down your whole app, I mean the whole coroutine that is launching child coroutines, but right now that looks like it is your whole app.